# DB Date insert works sometimes

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-3.0, asp.net-3.5

I have the following line:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8).Value = date_of_trip;
```

where `date_of_trip` is a string containing `25-9-2013` (i.e. day-month-year)

This gives me an error message:

> System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert 25-9-2013 to System.DateTime.
>   Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: String was not
>   recognized as a valid DateTime.

However, if `date_of_trip` is `1-1-2013`, it seems to work perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the string to `datetime` before you send it to the db.

For example:

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParse(date_of_trip, out dt))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8).Value = dt;
    // ...
}
else
{
    // you should use a CompareValidator to check if it's a valid date
}
```

If you want to ensure that your given format will work even if the current-culture of the server will change you can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` with format `"dd-MM-yyyy"`:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date_of_trip, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: For your `TryParseExact` example, I am getting `The name 'DateTimeStyles' does not exist in the current context`?

Comment: [**It's**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx) in `System.Globalization` namespace, so either add the using or write `System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None` explicitely (edited the answer).

Comment: Done, but I'm now getting `The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.TryParseExact(string, string[], System.IFormatProvider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles, out System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments`.

Comment: I'm using [this overload of `TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) which exists since .NET 2. Note that `date_of_trip` is a `string` and `dt` is a `DateTime` variable (see my first code sample).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because the server expects the first parameter to be a month. Try to use a real DateTime or the format yyyy-mm-dd (i.e. 2013-09-25), which should always work.